# Paragraph spacing with exam class

Tags: paragraphs, exam, parskip

I use the exam class to prepare exams. I prefer to have questions with no indentation and a space between paragraphs, so I use parskip. However, I find the space between paragrapsh and between questions too narrow.

How can I increase the space between paragraphs?

Here follows a MWE with the packages that I commonly use and an image of the page generated with it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=black}
\urlstyle{rm}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\Large Exam \verb|\documentclass|
\end{center}

Using \verb|\usepackage{parskip}|, with 12pt font. Exam instructions given here. Exam instructions given here. Exam instructions given here. Exam instructions given here.

Another paragraph. Exam instructions given here. Exam instructions given here. Exam instructions given here. Exam instructions given here.

\begin{questions}

\question[5] This is the first question of the exam. This is the first question of the exam. The equation is%
\begin{equation}\label{eq010}
x^{2} + y^{2} = z^{2}.
\end{equation}
This is the first question of the exam. This is the first question of the exam. This is the first question of the exam.

Another paragraph. This is the first question of the exam. This is the first question of the exam. This is the first question of the exam.

\begin{parts}

\part First part of the question. First part of the question. First part of the question. First part of the question. First part of the question. First part of the question. First part of the question. First part of the question. First part of the question.

\part Second part of the question. Second part of the question. Second part of the question. Second part of the question. Second part of the question. Second part of the question. Second part of the question. Second part of the question. Second part of the question. 

\end{parts}

\question[5] This is the second question of the exam. This is the second question of the exam. This is the second question of the exam. This is the second question of the exam. The equation is%
\begin{equation}\label{eq020}
x^{2} + y^{2} = z^{2}.
\end{equation}
This is the second question of the exam. This is the second question of the exam. This is the second question of the exam. This is the second question of the exam.

Another paragraph. This is the second question of the exam. This is the second question of the exam. This is the second question of the exam. This is the second question of the exam.

\begin{parts}

\part First part of the question. First part of the question. First part of the question. First part of the question. First part of the question. First part of the question. First part of the question. First part of the question. First part of the question.

\part Second part of the question. Second part of the question. Second part of the question. Second part of the question. Second part of the question. Second part of the question. Second part of the question. Second part of the question. Second part of the question. 

\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see that exam class does not set \parskip or \parindent, which is basically all that the parskip package does (based on the manual).  It should also me noted that questions etc. are implemented as lists and can have their spacing adjusted independently.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Is it possible to adjust the space between questions and the space between question parts separaterly?

Comment: Yes.  Use `\renewcommand{\quesetionshook}{\setlength{\itemsep}{...}}` and `\renewcommand{\partshook}{\setlength{\itemsep}{...}}` (page 40).

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I will use it, too. If you want to add this suggestion as an answer, it would be nice.

Comment: Don't need the points.  AFAICT, there are no more super powers to gain.

Comment: :). That is fine. Thank you

Comment: @JohnKormylo For those who copy-paste, there is a little typo in your answer. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the default space between paragraphs via

```
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
```

where `1em` can be changed to the desired length.

Comment: Thanks. Can it clash with the parskip package? How do you choose the measure? I checked the default for \parskip in the document above and it is 7.25pt plus 2.0pt. The measures 1em or 1\baselineskip usually work fine for this kind of document?

Comment: See also the comments above, on the question, about the space between questions and parts.